# My sword is swinging not the way I want it to go?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I just added a sword swinging script to my sword, and it works fine. But I just want my sword to go forwards. It goes side to side, and random ways to when I turn. Is there any way I can fix this? Thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Sword : MonoBehaviour {

private float swingDuration = 0.5f;
private float swingSpeed = 0.22f;

private float swingTimer = 0f;
private bool swinging = false;
private Vector3 startRot;

void Start () {
    startRot = transform.eulerAngles;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !swinging) {
        swinging = true;
    }   

    if (swinging) {
        swingTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (swingTimer < (swingDuration / 2)) {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startRot, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), swingSpeed);
        }

        if (swingTimer > (swingDuration / 2)) {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.eulerAngles, startRot, swingSpeed);
        }

        if (swingTimer > swingDuration) {
            swingTimer = 0f;
            swinging = false;
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: First impression: The cases `(swingTimer < (swingDuration / 2))` and `(swingTimer > (swingDuration / 2))`are handled differently. In the first case the calculated `transform.eulerAngles` will always be the same.

Comment: I'm not following you. sorry

Comment: I don't understand how you're explaining it. Are you saying I should just delete one of the lines or add something?

Comment: (1) The arguments of  `Vector3.Lerp(startRot, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), swingSpeed)` are always the same. I.e. the function value will not change. (2) I would expect the third argument to be a changing value in the range of [0..1] - e.g swingTimer *2 / swingDuration.

Comment: 2 nd point: `transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.eulerAngles, startRot, swingSpeed)` changes the `to` position (1st argument) from call to call, The "swing" should be done by the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

Vector3.Lerp has this signature:

```
public static function Lerp(from: Vector3, to: Vector3, t: float): Vector3;
```

Where t is within [0..1], For t=0 you get `from` for t=0 you get `to` ad a result. I.e.the "swing" effect comes from the third argument which is constant in your case. a reasonable argument would be something like

```
swingTimer *2 / swingDuration
```

or (for the "back swing")

```
(swingTimer-swingDuration/2) *2 / swingDuration
```

Another problem is that you change the `from`angle (1 argument) instead of the 3rd argument:

```
 transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.eulerAngles, startRot, swingSpeed);
```

This causes the "random" effect, which you experienced.